# mat-checkbox alway show 'Y'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using angular material 7. I using mat-checkbox.. When 'Y' is checked and when 'N' is not checked. But my checkbox always show y and checked when status is 'N'.

HTML

```
<form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm)" class="form-horizontal row-border">
<input matInput type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="userId"
[ngModel]="selectedRow?.userId" [readonly]="selectedRow?.userId" id="userId"
                                        required>
<input matInput type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="userName"
[ngModel]="selectedRow?.userName" id="userName" required>
<mat-checkbox type="text" name="blocked" [ngModel]="selectedRow?.blocked"
                                                id="blocked" (change)="(selectedRow?.blocked?'Y':'N')">{{selectedRow?.blocked}}</mat-checkbox>
<button type="submit" mat-flat-button color="primary">submit</button>
</form>
```

**Component**

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm ){
    // let value = this.selectedRow.blocked == true ? 'Y' : 'N';
    let data = form.value;
    console.log(data)
}
```

**Service**

```
export interface UserInfo {
    userId: string;
    userName: string;
    blocked: string;
  }

export class User implements UserInfo  {
    userId = '';
    userName = '';
    blocked = '';

    constructor(json) {
      if(!json){ return }
      this.userId = json.userId || this.userId;
      this.userName = json.userName || this.userName;
      this.blocked = json.blocked ? 'Y' : 'N';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your case `NgModel` is a one-way binding, the value of `selectedRow?.blocked` is not changed upon check/uncheck, therefore you should change your `mat-checkbox` in html to:

```
<mat-checkbox type="text" name="blocked" [ngModel]="selectedRow?.blocked"
     id="blocked" (change)="selectedRow.blocked = $event?'Y':'N'">
    {{selectedRow?.blocked}}
</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: I got error `core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 24 in [selectedRow?.blocked = $event?'Y':'N'] in ng:///UserModule/UserComponent.html@270:61 ("ked" [ngModel]="selectedRow?.blocked"
                                                id="blocked" [ERROR ->](change)="selectedRow?.blocked = $event?'Y':'N'">{{selectedRow?.blocked}}</mat-checkbox>
           "): ng:///UserModule/UserComponent.html@270:61`

Comment: forgot to remove the `?` in `(change)="selectedRow.blocked = $event?'Y':'N'"`

Comment: I've change in service `this.blocked = json.blocked || this.blocked;` and status changed but the problem...checkbox always checked when status is 'N'

Comment: It work now... I've change `[ngModel]="selectedRow?.blocked === 'Y'"` Thanks for your help